# How to visualize sensor data vs time with kibana?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5

How to visualize sensor data vs time in kibana, I have pushed the data to form SQL server to kibana but I'm unable to visualize it.

Comment: Why not include some examples of what your data looks like? What about defining an axis that you would like to see against time? Your question needs more detail.

Comment: I have collected the heart beat using the sensor and I want to display it in in a graph against time

Comment: I'm collecting the heart beat, speed, location, temperature and humidity and push it to the data base, however I have pushed this data to kibana and i'm trying to display it in a graph and it should be a real-time graph.